# Numo::NArrayで定義した配列の標準出力方法について

Tags: ruby

Numo::NArrayを用いて数値計算をしようと考えています．
そこで，以下のようなテストコードがあったとき，算術演算後の演算結果を標準出力したいのですが，下記に示すような標準出力になってしまいます．
どのようにしたら配列の中身を標準出力できるのでしょうか．

初めてNumo::NArrayを利用するのでわかりません．
ご教授宜しくお願い致します．

```
require 'numo/narray'

list_size = 1_000_000
range = (-100.0 .. 100.0)

# Numo::NArray型に格納する配列を定義
out1 = Array.new(list_size) do 
  rand(range) + rand(range) * 1i
end
out2 = Array.new(list_size) do 
  rand(range) + rand(range) * 1i
end

# Numo::NArray型を定義
out1_na = Numo::DComplex.new(list_size)
p "Defined: out1_na = #{out1_na}"
out1_na.store(out1)                     # 配列out1を格納

out2_na = Numo::DComplex.new(list_size)
p "Defined: out2_na = #{out2_na}"
out2_na.store(out2)                     # 配列out2を格納


# 算術演算でテストする
print "和算"
plus = out1_na + out2_na
puts ": #{plus}"

print "減算"
minus = out1_na - out2_na
puts ": #{minus}"

print "乗算"
product = out1_na * out2_na
puts ": #{product}"

print "除算"
per = out1_na / out2_na
puts ": #{per}"
```

出力結果

```
$ ruby test_numoNArray.rb 
"Defined: out1_na = #<Numo::DComplex:0x00007fe91b1f3b58>"
"Defined: out2_na = #<Numo::DComplex:0x00007fe91b1f37c0>"
和算: #<Numo::DComplex:0x00007fe91dd4bd50>
減算: #<Numo::DComplex:0x00007fe91dd4b9b8>
乗算: #<Numo::DComplex:0x00007fe91dd4b6c0>
除算: #<Numo::DComplex:0x00007fe91dd4b440>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

p メソッドで配列の内容を表示できます。要素数が多い場合は初めの方だけ表示します。

```
x = Numo::DComplex.new(5,4).seq
p x
```

出力

```
Numo::DComplex#shape=[5,4]
[[0+0i, 1+0i, 2+0i, 3+0i], 
 [4+0i, 5+0i, 6+0i, 7+0i], 
 [8+0i, 9+0i, 10+0i, 11+0i], 
 [12+0i, 13+0i, 14+0i, 15+0i], 
 [16+0i, 17+0i, 18+0i, 19+0i]]
```

Comment: 私の場合，演算結果を`p`（標準出力）してもオブジェクトIDしか表示されないのですが，これはなぜでしょうか．

Comment: オブジェクトIDが出力されるのは、to_s メソッドが呼ばれているからです。Ruby では `puts "#{out1_na}"` は `puts "#{out1_na.to_s}"` と同等です。一方、配列内容を含む文字列に変換するメソッドは inspect です。上の例では `puts "#{out1_na.inspect}"` とする必要があります。 Rubyでは `p x` は `puts x.inspect` と同等です。